# If utilizing a pointer attribute for a class to access the heap, how does one avoid the non-scalar type error?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, heap-memory

This is the header for the class in question. The idea is to have a class that acts like a pointer to access the heap. So far I have this.

```
#ifndef PTR_H_
#define PTR_H_

template < typename T >
class ptr
{
private:
    T * p;
public:
    ptr< T >()
        : p(new T)
    {

    }
    ptr< T >(ptr & pt)
        : p(pt.p)
    {

    }
    ~ptr()
    {
        delete [] p;
    }
};



#endif
```

I've kept them all inline for simplicity sake but all said and done, I'm running into a wall. I'm trying to have it access the heap right away and I'm already getting the non-scalar type issue.

Here's the main.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ptr.h"

int main()
{
    ptr< int > p = new int;

    return 0;
}
```

My question is pretty simple since I'm still new C++ OOP, what exactly did I do wrong and what are some guidelines I need to know to avoid this issue in the first place?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, exactly? I don't know what it means to "access the heap". And what is the actual problem you're having? And what is the error message? All you've described is _"the non-scalar type issue"_ and _"the non-scalar type error"_. Pretend we have not seen your code or your problem before, and explain it clearly, in exact terms.

Comment: Do you know what `new int` gives you? Do you have a constructor that accepts a value of that type?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit 
The idea is simple. Just access more data with a class that is "acting like a pointer." Basically I want to access the heap (ie get more free store data) and then have that pointer equal to a value that is of the type specified by a type template. The error says invalid conversion from *int to a nonscalar type 'ptr< int >'

Comment: Sorry, I still don't follow your goal. "Access more data"? "A class that is 'acting like a pointer'?" "Get more free store data"? "Pointer equal to a value"? None of these things makes sense, sorry. We can solve your syntax error (see my leading question, and the answer below) but I am no closer to solving your more broader design problem. Let's try to reframe it. What design or language limitation prompted you to make this class? What problem did you encounter that led you to decide that you needed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error "invalid conversion from *int to a nonscalar type 'ptr< int >'" is caused by your declaration `ptr<int> p = new int`. `ptr<int> p` is already enough. If you are not doing this to learn, you should use `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` instead.

If you want to make your declaration possible, you will have to make a custom constructor like this `ptr<T>(T* t) : p(t) { }`.

Comment: THANK YOU! I'm really doing this for some new knowledge on smart pointers. I know it isn't necessary but I figured I might as well give it a go.

Comment: One other thing too, I did get an error saying "invalid initialization of non-const refer of type 'ptr<int>&' from an rvalue of type 'ptr'. Would proper assignment operators fix this in my class?